# MATLAB : How to set matrix by matrix of index?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I'd like to ask how can I set in MATLAB matrix :

|1 4 5|
|2 9 1| =A,
|5 1 3|

|1 3 2|
|2 1 3| =INDEX, it says which positions should placed elements of matrix A
|3 2 1|

Like this : ( it will be an output )

|1 5 4|
|9 2 1| =MATRIX,
|3 1 5|

I'll be glad to have an answer :) Thank you

Comment: define A and B as `A=([1,4,5;2,9,1;5,1,3])'` and `B=[1,3,2;2,1,3;3,2,1]+[0,0,0;3,3,3;6,6,6]` and then apply `A(B)` ( its not an elegent indexing, but actually works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here two solutions provided:

Using `accumarray` :

```
[row_idx, ~] = find(INDEX);
result = accumarray([row_idx(:) INDEX(:)], A(:), size(A));
```

Using `sub2ind` :

```
s = size(A);
row_idx = repmat((1:s(1)).', 1, s(2));
idx = sub2ind(s, row_idx, INDEX);
result = reshape(A(idx), s);
```